# Validate through parents model fileds

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    to = models.ForeignKey(Place)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
```

I need to validate place field of Bar can be from or to. For example if I have from - London and to - New-York, I can choose place for child model only between this two places. How can I do in serializer? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `place` with `direction (bool)` and data will be always consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a custom validation for multiple Model fields you should use Model.clean()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)

    def clean(self):
        # Your check here
        if self.place: #between self.foo.from and self.foo.to
            #Your code here
            pass
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Place isn't between frow and to")
```